# Understanding questions like this: For which $p$ does $x-p\sqrt {x-1}$ have a minimum at $x=5$?

Tags: calculus

I'm not sure why I do not understand this question.

> $$f_p(x)=x-p\sqrt {x-1}$$
>   For which value of $p$ does $f_p$ has a minimum value at $x=5$?

I do understand when people ask me for a minimum value, I would need to check the extremes by solving for the functions derivative and equaling that to $0$. After that, I would just see what the value before $0$ and after $0$ is to check if that's a minimum or max point is (if at all).

Would love some mix of math - non math explanation for this question to understand it thoroughly. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure there's much intuition to be had here...just solve $f_p'(x)=0$ as a function of $p$, and then set that expression to $5$.

Answer (score 1):

You will have a minimum at $x=5$ if $f'(5)=0$ and $f''(5)>0.$

$$f'(5) = 1-\frac {p}{2\sqrt {5-1}} =0 \implies p=4$$

At $p=4$ we have $$f''(5) = 1/8 $$which is positive.

Thus$ p=4$ is the desired value.

Answer (score 0):

The first step consists in determining the extreme points. It is easy to see that if $p\leqslant0$, then $f$ is strictly increasing. So, let us assume that $p>0$. Then $f'(x)=0\iff x=\frac{p^2}4+1$. In particular, $5$ is an extreme point if and only if $p=4$. Since, in this case, $f''(5)=\frac18>0$, $f$ has a local minimum here. It's easy to see that it's in fact an absolute minimum.

Answer (score 0):

If you put in $p = 0$, you get the function 
$$
f_0(x) = x
$$
which doesn't have any minimum at all. If you put in $p = 1$, you get the function
$$
f_1(x) = x - \sqrt{x-1}
$$
which has a minimum at $x \approx 1.5$. (You can check this as you suggest by checking the extremes ($x = 1$ is the only extreme here) and checking where the derivative is zero...but I'm not going to do that for you here.)

If you put in $p = 7.3$, you get the function
$$
f_{7.3}(x) = x - 7.3 \sqrt{x-1}
$$
which has a min at about $x \approx 14$. Again, you can work out the details with the calculus you know.

Now if you did that work without an explicit value of $p$, you'd find that the min occurs at *some* value of $x$, but that this value depends on $p$.

You then have to adjust $p$ to make the min-point be $x = 5$.

Answer (score 0):

So $f_p$ is continuously differentiable over $(1,\infty)$ (that is just to make sure we can proceed just as you thought: derivating $f_p$).

Then, $f_p'(x)=1-p\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x-1}}$. Just computed the derivative for $x\in (1,\infty)$.

We would like to know the extremas in the general case to check where the minima and maxima are. We thus solve $f_p'(x)\geq0$:
$$
1-p\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x-1}}\geq0
$$
Since the square root is positive, that yields:
$$
\sqrt{x-1}\geq\frac{p}{2}
$$
And because $x\mapsto x^2$ is increasing over $(0, \infty)$:
$$
x\geq1+\frac{p^2}{4}
$$

Then, we realize that there is only one minimum value at $1+\frac{p^2}{4}$. And that equals 5 only if $p=4$.

Answer (score 0):

You want to set $f_p'(x)$ to $0$:

$$f_p'(x) = 1 - {p\over 2\sqrt{x-1}} = {2\sqrt{x-1} - p \over 2\sqrt{x-1}} = 0$$

And $f_p'(x)$ will only be zero if the numerator of the rational function is $0$ and the denominator is not. Thus:

$$f_p'(x) = 0 \implies 2\sqrt{x-1}-p = 0$$
$$2\sqrt{x-1}=p$$
$$\sqrt{x-1}=\frac p2$$

Plug in $x=5$, where you want the extreme to be:

$$\sqrt{5-1} = 2 = \frac p2 \implies p = 4$$

We can confirm it is a minimum by checking the second derivative, $f_p''(x)$:

$$f_p''(x) = 2p(x-1)^{-3/2} \quad f_p''(5) = 2 \cdot 4 (10 - 1)^{-3/2} > 0 \implies \text{Minimum}$$